# Backbone relational - cannot instantiate more than one ,,,

Tags: backbone.js, backbone-relational

I have been using backbone relational (https://github.com/PaulUithol/Backbone-relational) to build my application because I have a model (Room) with lots of other models attached:

- Room has many Comment
- Room belongs to Location

As you can see in [this issue](https://github.com/PaulUithol/Backbone-relational/issues/186) I keep getting the error

`Error: Cannot instantiate more than one Backbone.RelationalModel with the same id per type`

Whenever I change View or reload a Collection.

Now I know there is a thread [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12224122/backbone-relational-cannot-instantiate-two-relationalmodel-objects) where they suggest using `findOrCreate` but I am not accessing models individually, but am instead using `Collection.fetch`. Is there a way around this problem?

Comment: I had that problem... I don't knnow why but i deleted the reverse relation and problem solve by the moment...

Comment: Ahh. I didn't configure the reverse relations...

Comment: Take a look at this:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12224122/backbone-relational-cannot-instantiate-two-relationalmodel-objects#answer-12224192

Answer (score 2):

with backbone-relational you can get or create object from relational store. Use this to create relational objects:

```
this.model = someModel.findOrCreate({id: 123})
```

With this it will create new object or get existing one from relational store.

http://backbonerelational.org/#RelationalModel-findOrCreate

Comment: This would work but the models are being fetched dynamically, by the Collections.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem, fixed it by switching to Backbone-associations.

https://github.com/dhruvaray/backbone-associations

The interface is almost exactly the same with only a few minor differences so porting should be pretty simple.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem and it happend that I need to initialize model with function:

```
model: ->

   return new Project.Models.ModelName()
```

When you require_tree . in application.js then model files are loaded later than collection files (alphabetical order). Setting model with function waits until the app is executed.

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you mean... You mean before using `Collection.fetch()`, I should first instantiate a model?